# How do electrons interact with a graviton?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-gravity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The spin of graviton is 2 and spin of electron is $\frac{1}{2}$. Of course, since electrons have mass, they pull each other in respect to gravitational force.

Whenever i tried to draw Feynman diagram for this situation, i failed it due to the sum of spin for each vertex. Sum of spin of two electron can't be 2 which is spin of graviton.

I wonder how i should construct lagrangian term for this situation (2 fermion and a graviton) not violating spin conservation.

Comment: "due to the sum of spin for each vertex"  Do you have a reference for this statement? Are you forgetting angular momentum in your spin analysis?

Comment: In PHYSICAL REVIEW D 79, 053004 (2009) there are "Flavor changing fermion-graviton vertices"

Comment: @anna v do you mean each vertex do not need to conserve spin? or you mention angular momentum L?

Comment: there is no rule for conserving spin at a vertex as far as I know. See the diagrams in the paper above . the paper is in arxive too  https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3262

Comment: There's a nice paper describing the calculation [on the Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0607045).

Comment: See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0607045.pdf) paper by Holstein.

Comment: @anna v I understand. Then, is it right that the sum of spin for ' In ' and ' out ' state is same (not vertex including propagator. )

Comment: It depends on the particular conservation for the particular reaction. It is angular momentum that has to be conserved . The Pio in its rest frame has spin zero, the two photons of its decay have spin 1. You cannot just add up spins because as angular momentum there should be a direction also. In the pio case the two photons have opposite spin directions, which add up to the zero of the pion.

Comment: There are no gravitons.